# engine runs then overheats no hot air from defroster and water stays cool just replaced thermostat

Tags: overheating

My engine overheats, no hot air from defroster, water stays cool even after 20 min idling. it seems to be circulating and i put a new thermostat in. What could be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model/engine of the vehicle in question? This sounds like my '03 Civic LX.

Comment: There are quite a few factors that *could* cause an inability to warm. But as Paulster2 has noted, it's difficult to give applicable advice without knowing the year/make/model/engine info. :)

Answer (score -1):

Either your water pump is not working or your fhermosstate is installed backwords.